# Why does my prediction model keep giving a different prediction result every time I run it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have built a stock prediction model using LSTM. however, everytime when I run the program, the value of RMSE and the prediction result keep changing ( I did not change any data in the program. It giving out different result everytime when I clicking the run buttom everytime, ) Can anyone let me know what is the reason of it. Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You mostly need to provide some code for others to understand the problem easier. I suggest you to read this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should pass random_state or seed parameter to your model and you will get reproducible results every time. If you are using Keras, check this article. https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you know more about layers and some other basic things of neural networks.

**How does a neural network learn?**

A neural network contains three types of layers. Input, output, and hidden layers. All these layers contain neurons or you can say nodes. Every layer's neurons are connected with it's previous and next layer's neurons. Take a look at the picture below.
[image]

You can call the connections 'path'. Every path has some weights value. A neuron's input value is calculated by summing all the multiplications of outputs of previous layer's neuron and the path's weight value. Then the sum value is processed by some activation function. You can learn more about it by joining online classes or from tutorials.

But my point is, prediction completely depends on those weights. And those weights value keeps changing depending on the learning rate and some other stuff during training. What about the very beginning? at epoch no. 1? Basically model generates some random weights for all the paths. Then keeps changing those values during training to minimize the loss.

Every time you run your train, it generates random values. That's why you get different results each time. If you fix those values using tf.seed or some other method, you will get reproducible results. btw, you don't need to train every time. Save your model weights, then load it whenever you need to predict. You will get the same result every time you load the model weights and use that model to predict.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sources of randomness in machine learning (described in link below).
https://machinelearningmastery.com/randomness-in-machine-learning/

In this case it may probably be "Randomness in the Algorithm" even if you make sure to apply exactly same data in same order.